# Найти сумму последних отрицательных элементов в последовательности, введенных подряд

Tags: c++, массивы

Ввести последовательность чисел, количество которых заранее неизвестно. Признаком окончания ввода последовательности чисел является ввод подряд заданного в исходных данных чисел, имеющих одинаковые знаки. Вывести сумму последних в последовательности отрицательных чисел, введенных подряд.

Пример ввода:3      1,-2,-3,4,-5,-6,7,8,9
Ожидаемый результат: -11

Я сделал ввод массива до ввода определенного количества элементов подряд с одинаковыми знаками, но не могу понять, как посчитать сумму последних введенных подряд отрицательных элементов, если массив заканчивается не подряд введенными отрицательными числами, а положительными.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>    

using namespace std;

    int i,n,polozh,predel,otric,kolvo,j,sum,endf,w;
    int a[30];

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Vvedite kolichestvo elementov" << endl;
    cin >> predel;
    polozh=0;
    j = 0;
    otric=0;
    i=0;
    endf = 0;
    w = 1;
    while (endf==0)
    {
       cin >> a[i];
       if ((a[i] > 0))
        {
            sum = 0;
            otric=0;
            polozh++;
            if (polozh >= predel)
            {
                endf = 1;
            }
        }
        if ((a[i] < 0))
        {
            polozh=0;
            otric++;
            sum = sum + a[i];
            if (otric >= predel)
            {
                endf = 1;
            }
        }
        cout <<  " POLOZH =  " << polozh << endl;
        cout <<  " OTRIC =  " << otric << endl;
        cout << "SUMMA =  " << sum<<endl;
        i++;
        kolvo++;
    }
       for (i=0;i<=kolvo-1;i++) 
       {
        cout << a[i] << "  ";   
       }
system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вы на положительных элементах сумму не обнуляйте. А выставляйте какую нибудь переменную-флаг, что было положительное число. Когда встречаете отрицательное число и этот флаг установлен - обнуляете сумму и сбрасываете флаг

Answer (score 1):

Установить флаг проверки

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Vvedite kolichestvo elementov" << endl;
    cin >> predel;
    polozh=0;
    j = 0;
    otric=0;
    i=0;
    endf = 0;
    w = 2;
    while (endf==0)
    {
       cin >> a[i];
       if ((a[i] > 0))
        {
            if(w == 2)
              w = 1;
            otric=0;
            polozh++;
            if (polozh >= predel)
            {
                endf = 1;
            }
        }
        if ((a[i] < 0))
        {
            if(w == 1){
             w = 2;
             sum = 0; 
            }
            polozh=0;
            otric++;
            sum = sum + a[i];
            if (otric >= predel)
            {
                endf = 1;
            }
        }
        cout <<  " POLOZH =  " << polozh << endl;
        cout <<  " OTRIC =  " << otric << endl;
        cout << "SUMMA =  " << sum<<endl;
        i++;
        kolvo++;
    }
       for (i=0;i<=kolvo-1;i++) 
       {
        cout << a[i] << "  ";   
       }
system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вычитание отрицательного числа дает сложение с положительным. Сумма - это всегда сложение